# Quantum force and classical limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, semiclassical

Today my physicist friend told me about Bohmian mechanics as an alternative way of looking at QM.

He told me that in Bohmian mechanics the wave function gives rise to another fundamental force (the quantum force, as he called it).

**Is my understanding correct that we can get the classical limit for QM in this framework by assuming that this quantum force is too weak to influence the motion of big objects?**

Answer (score 0):

For a small time interval the quantum force can potentially be smaller than the classical forces and therefore be irrelevant.  And since it varies inversely with the mass, this is a possiblity.

However, the quantum force depends on the state of the wavefunction. So for a fixed mass, you can always find a wavefunction where the quantum force is large.  For instance it is fairly generic that an energy eigenstate has a quantum force that is equal and opposite to the classical force.  But energy eigenstates are not at all a classical limit.  I just want to point out that the high mass limit is not the limit you are looking for.

The small quantum force limit is exactly the limit you are looking for to get a classical limit. Regardless of whether you get there by a large mass or a good choice of wavefunction.

Also, a large mass should rightly be a limit of a large number of fundamental particles mutually interacting. Though obviously that is not a simple thing to model.